# Cannot mask mac address on MacOS Catalina

Tags: macos, network, wifi, catalina

Ever since updating to Catalina, I have been unable to mask my Mac Address in the same way I used to. Doing `sudo ifconfig en0 [mac]`, while the changes are reflected in `sudo ifconfig en0`, the changes are not reflected in the broadcasted Mac Address, which is apparent on the router settings, and when alt-clicking Wi-Fi symbol in the corner. Is this a known issue or is something wrong with my setup.

Comment: Why are you trying to change your MAC address?